# Unable to encode Url properly using HttpUtility.UrlEncode() method

Tags: c#, url, encoding

I have created an application in which I need to encode/decode special characters from the url which is entered by user.

For example : if user enters `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Å` then it's respective Url should be `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85`.

I made console application with following code.

```
string value = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Å";
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value));
```

It decodes the character `Å` successfully and also encodes `://` characters. After running the code I am getting output like : `http%3a%2f%2fen.wikipedia.org%2fwiki%2f%c3%85` but I want `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85`

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`Uri.EscapeUriString(value)` returns the value that you expect. But it might have other problems.

There are a few URL encoding functions in the .NET Framework which all behave differently and are useful in different situations:

1. [Uri.EscapeUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. [WebUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (only in .NET 4.5)
4. [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in System.Web.dll, so intended for web applications, not desktop)

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to select hostname and then urlencode only other part of string:

```
var inputString = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Å";
var encodedString;
var regex = new Regex("^(?<host>https?://.+?/)(?<path>.*)$");

var match = regex.Match(inputString);
if (match.Success)
    encodedString = match.Groups["host"] + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(match.Groups["path"].ToString());

Console.WriteLine(encodedString);
```